# Is preprocessing needed before prediction using FinalModel of RandomForest with caret package?

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction, caret

I use the caret package for training a randomForest object with 10x10CV.

```
library(caret)
tc <- trainControl("repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=10, classProbs=TRUE, savePred=T) 
RFFit <- train(Defect ~., data=trainingSet, method="rf", trControl=tc, preProc=c("center", "scale"))
```

After that, I test the randomForest on a testSet (new data)

```
RF.testSet$Prediction <- predict(RFFit, newdata=testSet)
```

The confusion matrix shows me, that the model isn't that bad.

```
confusionMatrix(data=RF.testSet$Prediction, RF.testSet$Defect)
              Reference
    Prediction   0   1
             0 886 179
             1  53 126  

      Accuracy : 0.8135          
             95% CI : (0.7907, 0.8348)
No Information Rate : 0.7548          
P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 4.369e-07       

              Kappa : 0.4145
```

I now want to test the $finalModel and I think it should give me the same result, but somehow I receive

```
> RF.testSet$Prediction <- predict(RFFit$finalModel, newdata=RF.testSet)
>  confusionMatrix(data=RF.testSet$Prediction, RF.testSet$Defect)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   0   1
         0 323  66
         1 616 239

               Accuracy : 0.4518          
                 95% CI : (0.4239, 0.4799)
    No Information Rate : 0.7548          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

                  Kappa : 0.0793
```

What am I missing?

edit @topepo :

I also learned another randomForest without the preProcessed option and got another result:

```
RFFit2 <- train(Defect ~., data=trainingSet, method="rf", trControl=tc)
testSet$Prediction2 <- predict(RFFit2, newdata=testSet)
confusionMatrix(data=testSet$Prediction2, testSet$Defect)

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction   0   1
         0 878 174
         1  61 131

               Accuracy : 0.8111          
                 95% CI : (0.7882, 0.8325)
    No Information Rate : 0.7548          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.252e-06       

                  Kappa : 0.4167
```

Comment: in the first instance, you predicted with a train object which you called `RFFit`, in the second time you predicted using the model object, I guess. So the difference might be in passing other things along with the train object that processed your new test data somehow differently than without using the train object.

Comment: For the 2nd `train` model you will get a slightly different result unless you set the random number seed before running it (see `?set.seed`). The accuracy values are 0.8135 and 0.8111, which are pretty close and only due to the randomness of resampling and the model calculations.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is the pre-processing. `predict.train` automatically centers and scales the new data (since you asked for that) while `predict.randomForest` takes whatever it is given. Since the tree splits are based on the processed values, the predictions will be off.

Max

Comment: but the `RFFit` object is created with the preProcessed `train` method...so it should return a centered and scaled object (shouldn´t it?). If so -> the `$finalModel` should also be scaled and centered

Comment: Yes but, according to the code above, you have not applied the centering and scaling to `testSet`. `predict.train` does that but `predict.randomForest` does not.

Comment: so there is no difference in using `predict(RFFit$finalModel, testSet)` and `predict(RFFit, testSet)` on the same testSet?

Comment: `predict(RFFit$finalModel, testSet)` and `predict(RFFit, testSet)` will be different if you use the `preProc` option in `train`. If you do not, they are training on the same dataset. In other words, any pre-processing that you ask for is done to the training set prior to running `randomForest`. It also applied the same pre-processing to any data that you predict on (using `predict(RFFit, testSet)`). If you use the `finalModel` object, you are using `predict.randomForest` instead of `predict.train` and none of the pre-processing is done before prediction.